# How to keep properties set in a console app

Tags: java

I've written code like the below.

```
public class Klazz {
    static int __prop = 10;

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        if ( args.length > 0 ) {
            String l = args[0];
            if ( l.equals( "-show" ) ) {
                System.out.println( __prop );
             }
             if ( l.equals( "-set" ) ) {
                 int np = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );
                 __prop = np;
             }
          } else {
              System.out.println( "No argument passed!" );
          }
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time i call `java Klazz -show`, `10` is shown - even if I called `java Klazz -set 12` before. How to make a passed value kept?

Comment: Well how would you expect the value to persist? You need to write it out to a file, or something similar that lives between times that you execute your program...

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword does not make a field persistent across multiple executions of your program. To persist the field value, you'll need to save it somewhere, e.g. in a file.

Since you're dealing with properties, you can use the [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to save and load from a `.properties` file:

> The `Properties` class represents a persistent set of properties. *The `Properties` can be saved to a stream or loaded from a stream*. Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables do not offer persistence across invocations of the same program. Once you set the variable to a new value, it is going to remain set for as long as the program is running, but as soon as the program exits, the value of that variable is gone with it.

If you would like to store the variable across runs, use some other mechanism for it - for example, saving the value in a file ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)).